# Format double to 2 decimal places

Tags: java

I am trying to Format my double value to exact 2 decimal places and it seems to working fine, here is the code i am trying

```
final NumberFormat df = DecimalFormat.getInstance();
df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
df.format(value)
```

Till now everything is working, but i need to return double value as it is being used for other calculations and i tried

```
Double.parseDouble(df.format(value))
```

with big decimal like

```
BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal(df.format(number));
```

but it is not working as expected 
like `18.50` is being converted as `18.5`

Though this is not an issue with calculations but i need to show amount on the UI where i have to show exactly up to 2 decimal places.

Is there any was i can handle it in java class or i have to take care in JSP with JSTL

Comment: I do not get it: what are you trying to print that does not print correctly?

Comment: @Vakh: i told that 18.50 is being returned as 18.5 when converted to double in end

Comment: Is [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatnumber_tag.htm) what you're looking for?  Or you could pass a String to your JSP.  It's hard to tell what you're trying to do and/or what you're expecting.

Comment: @jahroy: i am aware about JSTL approach, but that means adding the tag to every place where need to show the price, i want this to handle in java, sending string to jsp is like changing your existing data class and introduce additional field

Comment: I'm confused. Java does not store numbers in its internal formats.  When you say "*it is not working as expected like 18.50 is being converted as 18.5*" you're referring to their `String` representation. And whether you keep trailing zeroes or not depends on the conversion method.  If you do not want to deal with the presentation layer in your UI then you need to pass already formatted **strings**.

Comment: @PM77-1 - You and I have the same interpretation of this question.

Answer (score 2):

This is what `BigDecimal` is made for!

```
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal(123.456);
// set 2 fraction digits
// Note that setScale() does not change the original, 
// but returns a new BigDecimal.
number = number.setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN);
// get string representation
String text = number.toPlainString();
// get double value
double dbl = number.doubleValue();
```

And use `BigDecimal` for other calculations as well if you can.

Comment: Thanks for the input but `number.doubleValue()` for 18.50 will return 18.5 which means for the UI display i need to have another input field

Comment: @Umesh Why do you need another input field? A double will never ever be 18.50 Use a string representation instead.

Comment: @Umesh, I agree with @martini, use _string_ to respresent. You can use `DecimalFormat.applyPattern("0.00")` which is more simple.

Comment: @Hiway You have not used BigDecimals have you? toPlainString() is *the* simplest.